# How do I set a JSON response and retrieve that with jQuery form plugin?

Tags: jquery, json, response

In my server I've got the following code:

```
response.getWriter().write(myJsonString);
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
return null;
```

This returns the JSON object as a string (as in displays it on-screen) if I do a normal form submit or an AJAX jQuery submit. But when I add code from the malsup example at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#json to handle the response, I can't get the alert to display? I can't even tell if it's the response setting or the jQuery getting that's incorrect.

```
$('form[name=uploadForm]').submit(function() {
    //ajax form submission
    $('form[name=uploadForm]').ajaxSubmit({
        // dataType identifies the expected content type of the server response
        dataType:  'json',

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response
        // has been received
        success:   processJson
    });
    //cancels normal form submission
    return false;
});
function processJson(data) {
    // 'data' is the json object returned from the server
    alert(data.message);
}
```

I am open to options that eradicate the use of the form plugin (i.e. just using the `jQuery.post()` call).

Comment: What do you see in FireBug? Is the AJAX request being sent? What does the server respond to it?

Comment: Yeah the request is sent. I can debug it server side and it runs through that code still, but after returning null nothing happens. If I just use `.ajaxSubmit()` then the JSON is displayed on screen. I presume its a problem with the jQuery/javascript.

Comment: What do you see in FireBug as response from the server? What's the status code? What's the contents of the response. Also try subscribing to the error handler to see if it is not invoked.

Comment: 200 response from the server, with type set as `application/json`.